# Is there a device that can push down on a button with a wireless remote control?

Tags: remote-control, button, remote

I'm looking for a device, perhaps one that releases a small piston, tiny object, or block, that can press down on a button via wireless remote control. The button is about the size of a dime, and is sensitive enough it requires minimal effort to push.

The button is facing up, so I might not even have to mount the device on anything. Worse case scenario I'm hoping to duct tape the device over the button.

An alternative over a push-button could be a timed button. A device that can press down on the button every ~5 minutes.

Is there anything that's close to anything like this? I was hoping to find something from a marketplace website, but I've had no luck.

Comment: What is this button actually connected to?  It might be better to do a bit of surgery on whatever this button is part of...

Comment: sure, a radio control (as used for RC models) operating a servo could push a button.

Comment: What about a small push solenoid? https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11015

Comment: https://prota.info Not cheap, but a handy and versatile little device

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this product. it pushes what you want using WIFI and application control:
https://www.switch-bot.com/?fbclid=IwAR2hdh84V8mSksl3F3-UPTUy3m94_0usT6hSwtfWXaob61n4ANCWSfBwnWo

Comment: Why the downvote? This is an exact answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers here already that solve the problem directly as described, but I'm going to take a different approach to it.

If you have access to the electrical connections of the button you want to press, you could:

1. Get a small relay
2. Solder the contacts across the button with some small wire
3. Drive the relay coil from a cheap radio control car (replace the drive motor)

Look for a car that does not have speed control; just go/stop.

This approach would also leave the button uncovered and available for manual use.

Comment: or the type that have forwards, and turn when going backwards, put a diode in series with the relay coil so that it onlty energises when the reverse is triggered. (or remove the transistor that powers it forwards)

Comment: @Jasen Why would that be needed?  Sure, you're not going to use the other direction so it certainly *could* be removed or disabled with no harm to its new application, but why go to that trouble?  It's tethered now, so it's not like you're going to drive away or anything.

Comment: I meant the kind that have a one button remote that makes them reverse, else they go forwards all the time. you need to disable or block the forwards feature.

Comment: @Jasen Ah!  I see now.  Yes, then it would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Mechanical SLRs used a cable release to minimise camera shake. [Here's a hack](http://handya.co.nz/post/43777800968/wireless-remote-for-fuji-x100-camera-or-leica) (unfortunately on an external site) to make an remote controlled one. There were also pneumatic remotes - a rubber bulb connected to 5 - 10 m of micro-tubing ending in a mini piston to screw into the shutter release button. Perhaps one of these would be very easy to hack by just pressurising the tube with a small air pump - maybe using the bulb as the actuator.

[image]

*Picture from [sammys.com](http://www.samys.com/c/Cable-Releases--Remotes/start_25/2/141.html). (I've never heard of them before.)*

2. Lego Technics or Mindstorms must have had something with a remote?

Answer (score 0):

I can see a number of options

radio control servos (radio controlled model hardware) this stuff is well esablised technology: IIRC the IRA used to use these to detonate bombs.

a car  alarm. or garage door opener remote, and an auxilliary receiver driving a push solenoid

modify a wireless doorbell (especially one that has real chimes)

Answer (score 0):

this circuit will generate an approximately half second pulse every approx 5 minutes, and can drive a solenoid to press the button

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxXhRa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A small linear actuator solenoid allowing with a wireless relay module would work great. http://www.trossenrobotics.com/p/small-solenoid.aspx you would need to mount it so it can push the button, so you would need to build a small frame. It could be made out of wood, and attached to the button with some hot glue for a non permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bluetooth controlled button that is held in place using double sided tape (or glue if you want it to be permanent) called the Microbot Push 
https://www.amazon.ca/MicroBot-Push-Wireless-Automation-Platinum/dp/B01FQN2T2W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1493585609&sr=8-1&keywords=microbot+push